# How to display date under time in GNOME

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, date

In Ubuntu 18.04, my current desktop looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

How do I display date under time in GNOME panel as below?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: the second image you got it from other pc or your pc?

Comment: just edited.. but found a solution now to achieve that

Comment: Oh, thats nice. You can write your own Answer and accept it.

Comment: in clock override extension added this "  %I:%m %p%n %d-%m-%Y"

Comment: i tried your code. its nice. but alignment issues are there. its not perfectly in the center to each line.

Comment: ya that is still an issue. i managed with spacing though it is not a true solution.

Comment: yes, spaces is just a temporary solution at that moment only.. when number of digits and zeros comes up, it changes the alignment.

Comment: if found any alternative solution or update to this you are welcome to answer.

Comment: @SathishKanna The `Date Menu Formatter` extension also does formatting but has the added bonus of handling the centered alignment automatically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [clock override](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/) extension to achieve this.

After opening the extension's preferences, under "text to display instead of the clock" tab enter `%I:%M %p%n %d/%m/%Y`.

`%n` is responsible for next line and for the rest of formats check [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GDateTime.html#g-date-time-format).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nice catch! Thought this was not possible.

Answer (score 4):

this answer is only for ***"text alignment"*** purpose in continuation with the comments below the question and the already accepted answer.

when we enter next line by %n in the below field,
the lines are aligned to the left as shown in the below image.

[image]

to make this alignment to the center,
we need to open the `gdm3.css` file and edit the portion like below.

open the file by `sudo -H gedit /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css`
find the below section under "TOP BAR" line number around 743.

```
#panel.solid .panel-button:checked {
        color: white; }
    #panel.solid .system-status-icon,
    #panel.solid .app-menu-icon > StIcon,
    #panel.solid .popup-menu-arrow {
      icon-shadow: none; }
```

and add the below lines under the line `icon-shadow: none; }`

```
#panel .clock-display {
   text-align: center;
}
```

it looks like below after adding the required lines.

```
#panel.solid .panel-button:checked {
        color: white; }
    #panel.solid .system-status-icon,
    #panel.solid .app-menu-icon > StIcon,
    #panel.solid .popup-menu-arrow {
      icon-shadow: none; }
#panel .clock-display {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Save the file & Close.
Reboot to see the change.

[image]

[image]

Note: *if you use different shell themes than the default shell theme, you may search for the text `clock-display` in the respected `gnome-shell.css` file. if found, edit there, if not found add the lines as shown above.*

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeking an alternative solution, the `Date Menu Formatter` extension seems to offer the same formatting features with the added bonus of automatically handling centering the alignment.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4655/date-menu-formatter/